# Debugging Pl/SQL code in conjuction with SQL Developer and Oracle HTTP Server

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper, mod-plsql

Anybody have experience about conjunction Oracle Http Server and sql developer. I have web application that use pl/sql mod for get data. For example

```
function flist() {
var p=new revWindow("_chlist","dialogHeight: 450px; dialogWidth: 650px; resizable: yes;status: no; scroll: no;");
var obj=new Object();
obj.sizer=p;
rs=window.showModalDialog("!rev_xxx.getIssueList?_ref="+frnd()+"&_name=&_code="+ (_issue.value?_issue.value:""),obj,p.get());
if(rs) _issue.value=rs.channel_code;
}
```

So when i set breakpoint in

> !rev_xxx.getIssueList

and is triggered how i can set up sql developer for catch this breakpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little late but just as a suggestions if this is still an issue:

- don't debug but rather trace to trace PL/SQL code
- just write to a simple logging table

Example:

```
create table logtab(ts timestamp default current_timestamp, tx varchar2(2000));
/
create or replace procedure log(tx in varchar2) is
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
   insert into logtab(tx) values (tx);
   commit;
end;
/
```